# In class without a property called "type" I get org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a setter for property type in class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Using JPA, and Hibernate as the provideer, I have a class defined like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="partyrole")
public class PartyRole extends BaseDateRangeModel {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  private Party roleFor;

  public void setRoleFor(Party roleFor) {
    this.roleFor = roleFor;
  }

  @ManyToOne
  public Party getRoleFor() {
    return roleFor;
  }
}
```

And I get the error in title of the question.  I've tried adding `public void setType(Object type)` but that doesn't work either.  The persistence.xml file is normal.
There are two classes that reference this one, but neither of them attempts to invoke `setType` either. I'd apprecaite any help!!!!
This happens at deployment time.  The stack trace is at the bottom.

The Parent Class:

```
package com.nsfw.bmp.common.jpa;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

import org.hibernate.validator.AssertTrue;
import org.hibernate.validator.NotNull;

/**
 * Several models are date range sensitive, this base class provides that basic
 * functionality.
 * 
 * @author jim
 * 
 */
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseDateRangeModel extends BasePersistentModel {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Date from;
private Date thru;

/**
 * Determines if a model is active. A model is active if now is after or
 * equal to from , and thru is either null, or after now, or equal to now.
 */
@Transient
public boolean isActive() {
    Date now = new Date();
    boolean afterFrom = from.before(now) || from.equals(now);
    boolean beforeThru = thru == null || thru.after(now)
            || thru.equals(now);
    return afterFrom && beforeThru;
}

@AssertTrue(message = "Dates are not valid the thru date must be empty, or after the fromdate.")
public boolean areDatesValid() {
    if (thru == null) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return thru.after(from);
    }
}


@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "fromDate")
public Date getFrom() {
    return from;
}

public void setFrom(Date from) {
    this.from = from;
}

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
public Date getThru() {
    return thru;
}

public void setThru(Date thru) {
    this.thru = thru;
}
```

}

Its parent:

```
package com.nsfw.bmp.common.jpa;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;
import javax.persistence.Version;

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BasePersistentModel implements Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected Long id;

protected Long version = 0l;

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    BasePersistentModel other = (BasePersistentModel) obj;
    if (id == null) {
        if (other.id != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
        return false;
    if (version == null) {
        if (other.version != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!version.equals(other.version))
        return false;
    return true;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

@Version
public Long getVersion() {
    return version;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((version == null) ? 0 : version.hashCode());
    return result;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setVersion(Long version) {
    this.version = version;
}
```

}

The Party class is fairly large, with a lot of mappings.  This is the one asked for:

```
/**
 * @return the actingAs
 */
@OneToMany(mappedBy="roleFor", targetEntity=com.nsfw.bmp.party.entity.association.PartyRole.class)
@OrderBy("from")
public List<PartyRole> getActingAs() {
    return actingAs;
}
```

Here's the stack trace:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a setter for property type in class com.nsfw.bmp.party.entity.association.PartyRole
at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor.createSetter(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:240)
at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor.getSetter(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:233)
at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.getSetter(Property.java:299)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildPropertySetter(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:272)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.<init>(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:149)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:76)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.<init>(EntityEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.java:80)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:325)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:457)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:131)
at org.hibernate.persister.PersisterFactory.createClassPersister(PersisterFactory.java:84)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:261)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1327)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:867)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:669)
```

Comment: When do you get the error? When you do insert / update? Run a query? Start the application? Can you post a full stack trace?

Comment: during deployment on the server.

Comment: Annotating the field rather than the method doesn't help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post your party class?  I have a suspicion that this has to do with your manytoone mapping.  Is there a type column in the partyRole table?

Comment: That was the answer, I had another issue that resulted in the same error (old code lying around)

Answer (score 0):

You problem might be linked to the BaseDateRangeModel class, because PartyRole extends it.
can you show us that class?

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting this during startup, it means you have a class somewhere referencing PartyRole via inverse relationship, e.g. something along the lines of

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity=PartyRole.class, inverse=true")
```

in some other entity. Set hibernate logging level to `DEBUG` - it should help you to narrow the problem.